# Polymorphism and private data members

Tags: c++, oop, architecture

First of all I want to make it clear that this question relates to Scott Meyers' book Effective C++ (3rd edition) and specifically *item 22: declare data-members private*

I do understand it mostly and am trying to apply some of the things to my code to start practicing it. However I have a case where I am not sure how to solve it. Basically I have some abstract interfaces and some inheritance looking like this.

```
class abstractSystem {
    ...
protected:
    AbstractThing *_thing;
}

class DerivedSystem : public AbstractSystem {
    // inherits _thing so we can use it here.
}
```

However this is not coherent to item 22. I figured that it is better to have an interface to the base class for the derived classes and this works somewhat nice in many cases, but in this case since polymorphism is used to decide the `_thing` we would make a copy of it in a getter so that in the derived system any time we need to access it we need to copy it.

So I am guessing that's not great, and to be coherent to *item 28: avoid returning "handles" object internals* I can't seem to figure out how to do it without copying `_thing`:

```
class AbstractSystem {
protected:
    AbstractThing thing() { return *_thing; }
private:
    AbstractThing *_thing;
}

class DerivedSystem {
    // now we need to use thing() to access _thing implying copy
}
```

Is this the way it must be done, and isn't it a bit hard on performance to copy (if done fairly often)?

I guess it might be my design that's wrong.

Comment: You're overthinking this. Scott Meyers recommends best-practices, not laws. If the derived class is gonna have access to _thing no matter what (and you don't need any getter logic), simply make the member itself protected.

Comment: I think you are correct, the answer (maked it as accepted) provide a way of handling it as good as it gets. But really it only becomes more difficult to understand, and making use of it is a nightmare, at least if you have to do non-const stuff to it, since then you would have to provide a non-const reference which clearly is a much worse idea than to have a protected member. I think the key here is pointing out that I fell victim to over-thinking, that helps me move on happy with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a reference to the 'thing':

```
protected:
    AbstractThing const& thing() { return *_thing; }
```

This would avoid copying the entire object.

Comment: Yes it kind of solves the problem, or it **does** in many ways, however it also is incoherent to *item 28: avoid returning "handles" object internals*.

Comment: Right, my example returning a regular reference would be considered a handle. I think returning a const reference, however, would fulfill the spirit of item 28. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I think that is as good as it will get, there are some points being made about the risk of *dangling handles*, but as this is inheritance I feel like it should be fairly dependable and predictable in that respect.